# In ANTLR v4, is there a way to list the next possible rules for a given rule?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, grammar

I've looked through the ANTLR book, but I haven't come across a way to get the next possible rules for a given rule.

For instance, with a test grammar like

```
grammar ArrayInit;
init : '{' value (',' value)* '}' ; 
value : init 
    | INT
    ;
INT : [0-9]+ ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

is there a way to iteratively go through the rules and list the next possible rules?

For something like the above grammar, I'd expect to be able to start with the `init` rule. When I give that `init` rule, I'd expect to get the next possible options of `{`, `value`, (`,` and `value`), and `}`.

This way I could figure out what next possible tokens might be. I would be able to start with the `init` rule, and iteratively move through the grammar, seeing that `init` -> `{ value }` possible with the comma variation.

I've looked through the ANTLR classes. I'm able to use the parser's `getRuleNames` function to get all the rules. However, I can't use that to determine which rules follow a given rule.

Answer (score 1):

Internally the parsing engine doesn't work in terms of rules, but of ATN states and will have to walk this augmented transition network to find states that follow a given state (also known as follow set).

For a single look ahead use the [LL1Analyzer](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/atn/LL1Analyzer.java) class from the runtime. For more complex lookahead, possibly collecting rule names search for a code completion engine (e.g. [antlr4-c3](https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr4-c3)).